# React listening to multiple input boxes and filtering a list based on the input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I have a `React` class in which I get a list of object and need to put them into a table. That part is working fine. Now I need to implement a filter for each title that if the user types something in that input box, then based on where it was (under header1, header2, etc), it will sort according to that and what was written in the box.

So lets say that `header1` would be `userID` and I would type in `23` into the input box under `header1`, then it would return only those items from the list where `userID` starts with `23`.

```
renderItems(myList) {
    return (
      <div className="report-table">
        <div className="report-table-header">
          <div className="report-table-cell">header1</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header2</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header3</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header4</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header5</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header6</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header7</div>
          <div className="report-table-cell">header8</div>
        </div>
        <div className="report-table-header">
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
          <div className="report-table-cell"><input></input></div>
        </div>

          {mySortedList.map(item => (
          <MyListItem key={item.id} {...item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Any suggestions that would get me started?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty trivial problem. You could either use a library for tables (literally any, e.g. https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table). Or you might write the code on your own. As long as the number of headers is static, you could collect the filter values into some object:

```
const filters = {
  name: '', // no filtering for this header
  city: 'island', // this header has a user input
}
```

Later you could use loadsh `_.filter(rows, filters)`

Answer (score 0):

So the basic React lifecycle is that you a `this.state` variable in your constructor() (with defaults). Use this to store both your search queries and your data.

You will need a  tag with your `<input>`/`<select>` controls, that have an `onChange()` event that triggers `this.setState()`. This will trigger `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`. Check if your search terms have changed, and then update `this.state.data` with whatever raw information you want to display in your list.

`render()` will then be able to loop/map over `this.state.data` to display your list.

Read up on the React Component Lifecycle

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Here is an example of some recent code I wrote showing this pattern.

- https://github.com/JamesMcGuigan/elasticsearch-tweets/blob/master/src/components/TweetHeatMap/TweetHeatMap.jsx
- https://tweets.elasticsearch.jamesmcguigan.com/ (webpage result)